# "More" menu doesn't appear in Ubuntu One browser interface, then how can I access the dropdown menu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I'm trying to remove a folder from my U1 storage. I've read that I should go to U1 in my browser, click "more" next to the folder, and a relevant dropdown will appear. It doesn't.

With files, yes, there is a More dropdown, it gives options to delete or download the file. But with folders, there is no dropdown. All that happens when I click "more" next to a folder is that a blank line appears under the folder, and if I click "more" again the blank line disappears.

I assume that's a bug ...? Or is it meant to be like that and I'm missing something?
Whatever, the result is that I can't do what I want, which is to completely remove a folder from U1.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add which browser are you using? It may be relevant.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.65 and Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks searchfgold789! - fixed.

I was using Firefox/23.0.1 (latest) on my Windows laptop.

The menu worked immediately I tried Chrome, and now it works in Firefox when I change one of the Privacy settings from "tell sites I don't want to be tracked" to "don't tell sites my tracking preferences".

Also now I make that privacy change, also the "more" menu for the individual files in Firefox gains an additional line, "publish file" (previously in Firefox it only had the lines "delete" and "download").

So Firefox is clearly at fault (it has several little bugs) but it appears there is something non-uniform in how Ubuntu one handles the line-items, in that some of them work under Firefox in all cases of the tracking setting, others not. Anyway, fixed from my point of view, thanks again.